# What is the most efficient way of creating a tf.dataset from multiple json.gz files with multiple text records?

Tags: tensorflow, filter, tf.data.dataset

I have thousands of json.gz files, each with a variety of information about scientific papers. For each file, I have to extract the relevant information - e.g. title and labels - to make a dataset, then transform it to a `tf.dataset`. However, it is poorly efficient since I cannot filter the subjects directly or shuffle them in a single step.

I would like to read them using `tf.dataset.interleave` in order to shuffle them, but also to filter them according to specific labels.

Here is how I'm doing it up to now.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import pandas as pd

#For relevant feature extraction

def load_file(file): 
  #with gzip.open(bytes.decode(file), 'r') as fin:        # 4. gzip
  with gzip.open(file, 'r') as fin:
      json_bytes = fin.read()  
  json_str = json_bytes.decode('utf-8')            # 2. string (i.e. JSON)
  bb = json.loads(json_str)
  bb = pd.json_normalize(bb, 'items', ['indexed', ['title', 'publisher', 'type','indexed.date-parts', 'subject']], 
                      errors='ignore')
  bb.dropna(subset=['title', 'publisher', 'type','indexed.date-parts', 'subject'], inplace=True)
  bb.subject = bb.subject.apply(lambda x: int(themes[list(set(x) & set(list(themes.keys())))[0]]) if len(list(set(x) & set(list(themes.keys()))))>0 else len(list(themes.keys()))+1)
  bb.title = bb.title.str.join('').values
  #bb['author'] = bb['author'].apply(lambda x: '; '.join([', '.join([i['given'], i['family']]) for i in  x]))
  bb['indexed.date-parts'] = bb['indexed.date-parts'].apply(lambda tpl: datetime.datetime.strptime('-'.join(str(x) for x in tpl[0]), '%Y-%m-%d').strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))
  #bb = bb.sample(n=32, replace=True)
  #return bb.title.str.join('').values, bb.subject.str.join(', ').values
  return dict(bb[['title', 'publisher', 'type','indexed.date-parts', 'subject' ]])


file_list = ['file_2021_01/10625.json.gz',
 'file_2021_01/23897.json.gz',
 'file_2021_01/12169.json.gz',
 'file_2021_01/427.json.gz',...]

    
filenames = tf.data.Dataset.list_files(file_list, shuffle=True)

dataset = filenames.apply(
    tf.data.experimental.parallel_interleave(
        lambda x: tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(tf.numpy_function(load_file, [x], (tf.int64))), cycle_length=1))
```

However, it results it a error:

```
InternalError: Unsupported object type dict
     [[{{node PyFunc}}]] [Op:IteratorGetNext]
```

Thanks